# Using Kile@Ubuntu and getting "*.cls file not found. \begin"

Tags: errors, kile

I've just started using LaTeX for an assignment and got this error:

```
File 'assignment_1.cls' not found. ^^M
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: You probably start your assignment with `\documentclass{assignment_1}`, which searches for `assignment_1.cls` - a document class file - that does not exist. Using `\documentclass{article}` would work and only saving your source code file as (say) `assignment_1.tex`. Give some feedback after the above suggestion.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you, that did the trick! But another problem came up: The built pdf file has only English symbols and characters, where as my assignment will contain Greek characters as well (greek text). What can I do about that?

Comment: I'll convert my comment into an answer, since that's the format of this Q&A. You subsequent comment would be a new question altogether. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question where you can link to this question to provide the background. Be sure to include a [**minimal** working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\documentclass{myclass}` requires a file `myclass.cls` to exist on your system. Since `assignment_1` is a non-standard document class, `\documentclass{assignment_1}` causes an

```
File 'assignment_1.cls' not found.
```

error. Rather use one of the standard document classes (like `article` - preferred in your case, `book` or `report`).